# Linking Tomcat to MYSQL on Openshift

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, openshift

I've a java web application running on openshift 3 online.
I'm rather new to this platform and not familiar to the usage of service and pods.

So currently i have 2 containers running. 
A. Web app
B. MYSQL

I've created environment variables to supply the MYSQL username,password,port and ip-address to the container A running the web application. However, it seem like when openshift creates a new pod, the ip-address changes. Is there any other way i could link the two container so that i don't have to rely on the ip-address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each service has a *name*/*domain name*. You should use their *name* to specify their location, rather than the IP address. Internally, the *name* will be resolved to the IP address.

You can find the name in the service details in the web console.

[image]

Comment: how do i determine the name/domain for my service?

Comment: when you create your mysql service, a connection url is given to you that contains the address; it might be given in the form of an environment variable like `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST`

Comment: The name/domain for the service is the actual name of the service as it appears in OpenShift. Run ``oc get services`` or look at the list of services in the web console. If you didn't change it, it may be ``mysql``. You can use that short name. In the web console when looking at a service you will find a ``Hostname`` field which displays a longer name which also works. Only need longer name if were accessing services across project if pod networking had been set up.